# python pexpect commands not executed in correct order

Tags: pexpect

I'm running python pexpect to automate an application called IRIS

I'm just entering a whole set of just 2 commands. For example:

```
    set db=##Class(SYS.Database).%OpenId("/document-txt")
    if db.Mirrored=0 {w "/document-txt/IRIS.DAT NOT mirrored"} else {w "/document-txt/IRIS.DAT mirrored"}
```

The first command sets variable db and the second command is an "if" statement in IRIS "objectscript"
which tests if the variable set in first command and outputs a text message

If I was entering the commands by hand the session should look like this:

```
    %SYS>set db=##Class(SYS.Database).%OpenId("/analytics")
    %SYS>if db.Mirrored=0 {w "/analytics/IRIS.DAT NOT mirrored"} else {w "/analytics/IRIS.DAT mirrored"}
    /analytics/IRIS.DAT NOT mirrored
    %SYS>set db=##Class(SYS.Database).%OpenId("/anlt-facts")
    %SYS>if db.Mirrored=0 {w "/anlt-facts/IRIS.DAT NOT mirrored"} else {w "/anlt-facts/IRIS.DAT mirrored"}
    /anlt-facts/IRIS.DAT NOT mirrored
    %SYS>set db=##Class(SYS.Database).%OpenId("/anlt-historylogs")
    %SYS>if db.Mirrored=0 {w "/anlt-historylogs/IRIS.DAT NOT mirrored"} else {w "/anlt-historylogs/IRIS.DAT mirrored"}
    /anlt-historylogs/IRIS.DAT NOT mirrored
```

This is what I'm getting [from the pexpect log]:

```
    %SYS>set db=##Class(SYS.Database).%OpenId("/trak/analytics")
    set db=##Class(SYS.Database).%OpenId("/analytics")
    %SYS>if db.Mirrored=0 {w "/analytics/IRIS.DAT NOT mirrored"} else {w "/analytics/IRIS.DAT mirrored"} set db=##Class(SYS.Database).%OpenId("/anlt-facts")
    if db.Mirrored=0 {w "/analytics/IRIS.DAT NOT mirrored"} else {w "/analytics/IRIS.DAT mirrored"}
    /analytics/IRIS.DAT NOT mirrored 
    %SYS>if db.Mirrored=0 {w "/anlt-facts/IRIS.DAT NOT mirrored"} else {w "/anlt-facts/IRIS.DAT mirrored"} 
    %SYS>if db.Mirrored=0 {w "/anlt-facts/IRIS.DAT NOT mirrored"} else {w "/anlt-facts/IRIS.DAT mirrored"}
    /anlt-facts/IRIS.DAT NOT mirrored 
    %SYS>if db.Mirrored=0 {w "/anlt-historylogs/IRIS.DAT NOT mirrored"} else {w "/anlt-historylogs/IRIS.DAT mirrored"}
    set db=##Class(SYS.Database).%OpenId("/anlt-local")
    if db.Mirrored=0 {w "/anlt-local/IRIS.DAT NOT mirrored"} else {w "/anlt-local/IRIS.DAT mirrored"}
    set db=##Class(SYS.Database).%OpenId("/anlt-localsys")
    set db=##Class(SYS.Database).%OpenId("/anlt-historylogs")
    %SYS>
    %SYS>if db.Mirrored=0 {w "/anlt-historylogs/IRIS.DAT NOT mirrored"} else {w "/anlt-historylogs/IRIS.DAT mirrored"}
    /anlt-historylogs/IRIS.DAT NOT mirrored
```

Can anyone see why pexect is not executing the commands in correct order? That is line by line

It seems to be queueing up some commands.

I've given 5 seconds to execute each command which should be ample.

This is the code:

```
    ----Starting the IRIS session
    s = pexpect.spawn('bash',echo=False)
    s.logfile=open("/tmp/IRIS.log","wb")
    s.expect('#')
    s.sendline('iris session')
    s.expect('%SYS>')

    ----Sending the commands from a file:
    file1 = open('/tmp/mstatus', 'r')
    for line in file1:
    s.sendline(line)
    try:
    status=s.expect('%SYS>')
    time.sleep(5)
    except pexpect.TIMEOUT:
    print(f"IRIS session command prompt at {count}.. timeout")
    s.interact()
    except pexpect.EOF:
    print(f"IRIS session command prompt at {count} - Child process died")
    s.interact()
    except pexpect.ExceptionPexpect as e:
    print(f"IRIS session command prompt at {count}")
    print(e)
    s.interact()

    file1.close()
```

Comment: Please indent your Python code so that it is readable and syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0):

When reading a file with `for line in file1`, each line includes the terminating newline character. `Pexpect.sendline(line)` adds another newline. You are therefore sending a blank command line after each command, and so getting two prompts, and mistakingly matching the second prompt.

Use `Pexpect.send(line)` instead.